# Basketball equivalent to soccer's "goal"

Tags: vocabulary

You say "goal" in soccer when the ball gets into the net. How about basketball, When the ball gets through the hoop?

Comment: Basket is the general term.  Sometimes it could be called a '2-pointer' or '3-pointer'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with Maulik, in that *basket* qualifies as a generic term roughly equivalent to *goal* in some contexts:

> Ronaldo scored a goal on the play. Lebron made a basket on the play.

However, it's not a perfect synonym. We're all familiar with the ecstastic call from the broadcasters at World Cup matches:

> Gooooooooooooooooooal!

I don't think a sportscaster in a basketball arena is nearly as likely to exclaim:

> Baaaaaas - keeeeeeet!

Also, if I'm summarizing a game, I might say:

> Ronaldo scored two goals.

but I don't think I'm likely to say:

> Lebron made seven baskets.

Instead, it would be:

> Lebron scored 14 points.

Similarly, I might ask my son (the striker), "Did you score any goals today?" but I would be more likely to ask my daughter (the point guard), "How many points did you score today?" (not, "Did you make any baskets today?")

I imagine this difference holds for two reasons: (1) there are far more points scored in a basketball game than in a soccer match, and (2) not all baskets are worth the same number of points.

So, the terminology goes more like this:

> Steve Kerr scored 21 points. He was 7 of 9 **from the field**, he made 4 of 6 **free throws**, and he made one **three-pointer**.

A three-point shot in basketball is sometimes called a three-pointer, although, with enough context, that can even be shortened to a single word: *three*.

> He made a three!

As Maulik's answer also hints, the term *field goal* can be used. That term isn't used so much conversationally, but you do see it on stat sheets, like this one:

[image]

3P refers to three-point shots, and FT refers to free throws. FG is field goals, which refers to, well, *baskets.*

Comment: But at least to a non-sports fan like me, it seems that the level of excitement for an individual basket would be much less than for a goal, since a hundred or so baskets might be made in any game, versus maybe half a dozen goals.

Comment: @jamesqf - I agree; that probably plays a factor, too. To the O.P. - I thought of one more: if the ball goes through the basket without touching the rim, that is sometimes called a [_swish_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/swish).

Answer (score 1):

You *make* or *shoot* a ***basket***.

OALD on it:

> [basket (n)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/basket?q=basket): *a point that is scored by throwing the ball through this net*

[This proves it further](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_goal_%28basketball%29):

> *In basketball, the term field goal refers to **a basket scored** on any shot or tap other than a...*

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in basketball when someone scores it is called a two pointer or a three pointer depending on the distance from where the throw has been made.

But when a player is fouled, depending on the game's context they can be awarded three free throw attempts, two free throw attempts or one free throw attempt each attempt valuing one point.

[More on this](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-point_field_goal) here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to soccer's [Gooooooooooaaaaaaaaal!](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pFDkMzoCtrA).

But in basketball  *scoooorre* or *she/he scooooorres!* is possible.

In hockey, *goooooaaal* is more likely than *scoooorrre*, although both are possible.

In baseball, it's back to *s/he scooorrrrres!* There are no goals in baseball, whereas in cricket everybody *snores*.

Comment: I agree that both are possible, but, in ice hockey, the exclamation _scoooore!_ is more prevalent than _goooal!_ – at least among sportscasters (both in the [playoffs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzN3ahO5C9E), and in the [regular season](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzaMGmt6Z68)).