# What to say when a child successfully throws a ball into a basket

Tags: phrase-usage, usage, verb-usage

Imagine the situation that I am playing  with my child and he is trying to throw a ball into a basket.

When he misses I can just say "**You missed :(**"

What can I say when he succeeds? (to let him know what happened or describe the result of his action)

Is the phrase '**You hit!**' sounds good in this situation?

Or maybe "**You have thrown the ball into the basket!!!** Good boy!"

Please, give me few correct possible phrases. Thank you!

**EDIT:** The 'basket' is not a 'basketball basket'. It is a kind of baskets for toys.

Comment: You can just say,  "Score!" or "He shoots, he scores!" "Good one"  "Nice shot" "Way to go" "< *your son's name* > for two."

Comment: Thank you, great examples! But what phrases with the same context can I use that have a meaning that the ball is in the basket?

Comment: Uhmm, those phrases all imply that.  You would not say any of those if the ball didn't go in the basket.

Comment: The typical phrase for describing a person's action when they've *made a basket* is ...  ***made a basket***:  Wow you just made a basket.  "Hey Mom, guess what, Billy just made three baskets in a row!"

Comment: If the shot was in any way difficult or tricky, you can use *hit a basket*:  Wow he just hit a 3-pointer.  Wow he just hit one from half-court.  He hit a 2-pointer at the buzzer.

Comment: What is the opposite of the phrase 'to miss the basket' that contains the word 'basket' ?

Comment: The opposite is "He made a basket"

Comment: "Nothing but net!", for a clean shot that doesn't touch the rim but plunges straight to the bottom.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/58029/3281.

Comment: Stay away from controversy! Just say... *"You did/missed **it**"* :)

Comment: It could be that English is lacking here because there's no doubt that in Spanish you would just say "canasta!" which means exactly what you want it to mean.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Except that the OP has never stated he is talking about a basketball net. He has said a basket.

Comment: @pazzo Sure. But if my memory serves me right, and I think you know it as well, the basket of early basketball had no net, I think. :-)

Comment: @chumakoff   What do you mean by basket? Pick the closest image: [Image 1](http://images.wisegeek.com/wicker-laundry-basket.jpg) or [Image 2](http://www.competitiveedgeproducts.com/images/90062%20Lifetime%20basketball%20goal%20slam-it%20ulitmate%20rim.jpg). There is some confusion as to what you mean.

Comment: @pazzo I mean something that looks pretty like the one on this Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball--in the photo: The first basketball court: Springfield College. It's neither of your baskets. :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Sorry, I was asking the OP. Asking you would never clarify the question. :) I had time to edit my comment to insert the OP's name.

Comment: @pazzo Ah, sorry about that! My browser just crashed (I just got another power outage), and when I restored the session, this page was the first thing I saw. So I thought you addressed me. Anyway, the original basket looks cute, doesn't it? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the age of the child, you could say

You did it!
You made it!
You got it (in)!
Good job!
Way to go!

I would not say

*You hit!

From your description I assume the child is about 4 years old (or maybe younger, since you say you are describing what happened); and also that when you say a 'basket' you mean a 'basket', and not a 'basketball net'. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are absolutely right! The child is 2 years old and the purpose is to teach him how to speak and how to describe a current situation and results of his actions. You are also absolutely right about a 'basket'. It is in fact a basket with toys). I am sorry that my question was not precise enough. Thank you very much for your remark! Will this comment change your answer ?

Comment: These are all good, but my upvote is specifically for _you made it_ which is an ideal "antonym" for _you missed_ in this context.

Comment: @chumakoff My answer does not change  because I already thought you were talking about a small child.